# EasyRTC Download Conversation

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, easyrtc

I'm developing **video chat/conferance** application on **node.js**.I want to download conversation from video chat/conference. How can I download **EasyRTC** Video Chat/Conference conversation? Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EasyRTC does not have feature to capture and download audio+videos conversations.

You can use `RecordRTC` to integrate with easyRTC so you can capture and download your audio+video conversations.

Refer: [RecordRTC](http://recordrtc.org/RecordRTC.html)